# Placement of Comments in For Loops

Tags: octave

Laziness on my part led to writing some for loops like so:

```matlab
z={};
  for i=2:length(a)
  temp=b{i};
  if(length(temp)==2)
    c=temp{2};
    d=strtrim(c);
    e=strsplit(d, ' ');
    z{(i-1)}=e;
  else
    z{(i-1)}={};
  endif
endfor
%comment explaining indexing choices
```

but I wanted to annotate in-line for someone else who was viewing it, changing instead to:

```matlab
z={};
  for i=2:length(a)
  temp=b{i};
  if(length(temp)==2)
    c=temp{2};%Comment explaining this indexing choice
    d=strtrim(c);
    e=strsplit(d, ' ');
    z{(i-1)}=e;
  else
    z{(i-1)}={};
  endif
endfor
```

where the only difference is that the comment was moved both inside the loop and at the end of a line with a critical intermediate step. The change caused this working loop to immediately crash.

TL:DR: Is anyone aware of a stipulation in Octave that comments must be on their own lines?

Comment: First, please properly indent your code. Second, there's no reason that a comment should change the behavior of the code. I'll have a look and see if I can reproduce the problem. Edit: I can't... please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Edited for lovers of whitespace. Will upload minimal example later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's more likely that you introduced a syntax error while moving the comment (e.g. you probably removed the `;` at the end by accident). "Causing it to crash" isn't very informative, it would be a lot clearer if you included the error message.

However, to answer your question, there is *one* scenario where octave in particular disallows comments, and that's when you're performing string continuation over multiple lines, and in particular when using double-quotes:

```
mystr = "one \
  two, \ % this is the second number
  three.";
```

The above will fail because there should be *no* other character after the backslash other than the newline, *not even a single space*.

In this very specific case, you do indeed need to move your comment outside of the string construct:

```
mystr = "one \
  two, \
  three."; % line two refers to the second number
```

or, create the string in steps so you can comment:

```
mystr = ['one ',  ...
         'two, ', ... this is the second number.
         'three'];
```

Note the '...' acts as a comment operator, so no % needed here.

Comment: Fantastic! I figured it was something to do with the parsing of the data and how line continuation markers were handled.